# coloring dendogram object in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a dendogram looking like object. (in this example, for simplisity, I used phytreeread from Bioinforamtics toolbox)

```
tree.newick = '(A1:7,(B1:5,((G1:3, H1:3)C1:1, D1:4)F1:1)E1:2)O1:0';
mytree = phytreeread(tree.newick);
h = plot(mytree,'Type','square')
```

I also have of terminal nodes as well as internal nodes.
[image]

I can list the edges with

```
h.BranchLines
```

and change its color with

```
set(h.BranchLines(1),'Color',[1 1 0])
```

but, to make it automatic, I need to know, what are the nodes, at two ends of h.BranchLines(1), and I can't figure it out.

Basically, I am after making a function color_edge(A, B, color), to color the edge between node *A* and node *B*.

In other words, I would like to know either how,
1) for a given h.BranchLines(1) - how to figure out two ending nodes id
2) for a given two nodes, say *A1* and *O1* figure out, what is the which h.Branchlines is connecting them.

Code to reproduce the plot - you would need to have the bioinformatics toolbox

```
tree.newick = '(A1:7,(B1:5,((G1:3, H1:3)C1:1, D1:4)F1:1)E1:2)O1:0';
tree.root = {'O1'};
mytree = phytreeread(tree.newick);
phytreeviewer(mytree)
h = plot(mytree,'Type','square')
set(h.BranchLines(1),'Color',[1 1 0])
set(h.BranchLines(4),'Color',[0 1 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getmatrix](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/getmatrixphytree.html) function to extract the relationship, e.g. in your case:

```
>> [matrix, id] = getmatrix(mytree)

matrix =

   (9,1)        1
   (8,2)        1
   (6,3)        1
   (6,4)        1
   (7,5)        1
   (7,6)        1
   (8,7)        1
   (9,8)        1


id = 

    'A1'
    'B1'
    'G1'
    'H1'
    'D1'
    'C1'
    'F1'
    'E1'
    'O1'
```

It is not documented anywhere that the order of non-zero entries in the sparse `matrix` corresponds to the order of line handles in `BranchLines`, but it does seem to be the case (apparently, by construction). So e.g. the first handle would connect nodes 9 and 1, i.e. `O1` and `A1`, according to `id` mapping.

Worth noting that `plot` and `getmatrix` are not built-in functions, so you can just examine the source code to verify this assumption (though they are not the easiest to read). Sources are located under `\toolbox\bioinfo\bioinfo\@phytree\`.

Alternatively, we can do a quick check by showing branch labels on the chart, e.g. for the first line:

```
h = plot(mytree, 'Type', 'square', 'BranchLabels', true);
set(h.BranchLines(1), 'Color', 'r')
```

[image]

Finally, this is how you can read those non-zero node indices programmatically and in the right order:

```
[i,j] = ind2sub(size(matrix), find(matrix))

i =
     9
     8
     6
     6
     7
     7
     8
     9


j =
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
```

P.S. There is obviously absolutely no guarantee it will not break in the future release.